# Is it possible to use kafka source in spark streaming without replaying logs from last checkpoint?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using pyspark streaming to process a very large streaming log, and because the log is very huge I don't want spark to process old logs if the application fails for any reason.

I can delete the checkpoint directory and get what I want but I was wondering if there is any way to do it programmatically.

I have already tried `KafkaUtils.createStream(..., karkaParams={'auto.offset.reset': 'largest'})` but no success.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'
```

if you want to skip old messages in queue for your consumer group name when your application starts.

- Largest means "get me messages which my consumer group did not received never"
- Smallest means get messages from now on.

Also for future reference, if any one wants every available message in topic when application starts, you should use different consumer group name in every time and pass "**largest**" as offset.